# IOS Coredata. Is it possible to see saved data without fetching it

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am working on core-data base project. I want to know that is it possible to see which data are saved in coredata without fetching it ?

For example:

I am using this Tutorial  to learn coredata. **

> [Core Data demo from AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/)

I have implement below method to save the data in Data-model.(coredata)

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

// Create a new managed object
NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Device" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newDevice setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
[newDevice setValue:self.versionTextField.text forKey:@"version"];
[newDevice setValue:self.companyTextField.text forKey:@"company"];

NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

but i want to know that, is it possible or is there any way to see what data are saved in my data model without Implement it's fetching method ?

Fetch From Coredata:

[image]

Comment: check this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-managed-objects-and-fetch-requests--cms-21284

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. We can see saved data without fetching is .
After implement Save method core-data save sql file in Document Directory.

You can print it in nslog with using this Line.

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
```

and you can see full path of document folder printed in log like this.

> 2015-10-13 12:40:51.253 MyStore[1860:69256] file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C548BFA2-7B92-42E6-9D64-E16AFF0645D9/data/Containers/Data/Application/9C24913C-B295-4AA1-8DE9-A261CAA21624/Documents/

then you have to go in this folder. with selecting **G0-> Go to folder...** option.

[image]

Then print your Document path in go to folder window.

[image]

Note:- you have to write only this code in go to folder. (From  ~/Library )

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C548BFA2-7B92-42E6-9D64-E16AFF0645D9/data/Containers/Data/Application/9C24913C-B295-4AA1-8DE9-A261CAA21624/Documents
```

and press **GO** button.

you will find your sqlfile.

[image]

open it with using some sqllite reader software.

[SQL Lite pro](https://www.sqlitepro.com/)  this is the best software to read .sql file. open your file using it.

and you will see your saved data in it.

[image]

Comment: Here is the command for Swift:
`print(NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).last)`

Comment: And for Swift 3: `print(FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last)`

Answer (score 0):

During runtime: No.
That is due the nature of Core Data. It is an object graph, not a data persistence solution. A fetch doesn't return an object if he can choose.

Outside of your app it depends on the persistence if any. If you decided to go for a sql store, then consider the sql answer. If you did select a different store type, then it depends on the type you went for.

For most projects are basic foundation objects fine since they can be serialized. If you parse an JSON you get foundation objects back. Consider Core Data when you deal with bigger data that need to be searchable even when you don't have the data in memory.